# Looking for information about an old Patent

Tags: research, us1467558

I am researching the mechanical development of tools used by Fisheries in the Bristol Bay area.

I'm in possession of a tool marked, "OKILL'S PATENT PRESSURE INDICATOR, NEW TYPE PATENT No. 144034. This was one of the few tools which I was unable to find any information on.  I have not been able to find any record of the PATENT NO. 144034 and would appreciate any information regarding this particular model.

Here is the label on the tool:

```
              OKILL'S PATENT PRESSURE INDICATOR
                            N.D, 528
                           NEW TYPE
                            PATENT
                          No. 144034

                         G.TAYLOR (6) Ld
                             MAKERS
                             BOLTON
                         MADE IN ENGLAND
          (reverse side):              FERRIER & LUCAS
```

Any information that could point my research on this patent in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about the model and product are off-topic for Ask Patents.  See [faq](https://patents.stackexchange.com/about) for more information about which questions are on-topic here.

Questions about old patents are generally on-topic.  The entertainment value is high and the history of technology as expressed through patent documents is usually interesting to our community.

The original patent in question is from the United Kingdom, Publication Number GB144034A.  Published in 1920 and Invented by John Okill, a British citizen who lived in [Rock Ferry](https://www.google.com/maps?t=m&q=rock+ferry+map&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Rock+Ferry,+Merseyside,+United+Kingdom&z=6&vpsrc=0&iwloc=A) near Liverpool, England..

## 1. Original UK Patent: [GB144034A](https://mega.co.nz/#!w5BW0JLI!BenHJ0d3KN8BSsfdxRx93SmowfAm2yCkN14GCZDTYWc)

[image]

## 2. Related **US Patent Family member: [US1467558](https://www.google.com/patents/US1467558)**

[image]